# Не выводит последний элемент списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю Python.
Вот текст задания:

> Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).
>
> Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.
>
> Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.

Мой код:

```
    inp = list(map(int, input().split()))
    ls = [0]*(len(inp)-1)
    
    for i in range(0,len(inp)-1):
    if i==0:
        ls[0] = inp[0] + inp[len(inp)-1]
    if i==len(inp)-1:
        ls[len(inp)-1] = inp[len(inp)-2] + inp[0]
    if 0<=len(inp)<=1:
         ls[i] = inp[i]
    else:
         ls[i] = inp[i - 1] + inp[i + 1]
    

for i in range(len(inp) - 1):
    print(ls[i], end=' ')
```

Код выводит вместо n элементов n-1 элемент, последний элемент теряется.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
**UPD:**
Если кому-то пригодится, решила вот так:

    inp = list(map(int, input().split()))
    ls = [0]*(len(inp))
    
    for i in range(0,len(inp)-1):
            ls[i] = inp[i - 1] + inp[i + 1]
            ls[len(inp)-1] = inp[len(inp)-2] + inp[0]
            
    if len(inp)<2:
        for i in range(len(inp)):
            print(inp[i], end=' ')
    else:
        for i in range(len(inp)):
            print(ls[i], end=' ')
```

Comment: А для чего вы вычитаете в последнем цикле for?

Comment: Вычитаю единицу? Пишет out of range, если не вычитаю.

Comment: Уберите ```-1``` из ls и из последнего for. Тогда будет выводиться  5 цифр. Но я не понимаю почему последний именно 0 выводиться, не думал об этом. Если вас это интересует, то могу подумать

Comment: Ввод: 1 3 5 6 10
Вывод: 13 6 9 15 
То есть там даже не ноль. Последнего элемента просто нет. Я думала, что проблема может быть в количестве итераций первого цикла, но если честно, глаз замылился, просто не вижу уже.

Comment: Если у Вас есть более "питонный" вариант решения, можете его подсказать?

Comment: Я постараюсь решить вашу проблему

Comment: Спасибо!
Я сделала как Вы сказали, n элемент равен 0.

Comment: Можете расписать каждое условие, чтобы было проще читать его? А то лично я не понимаю, что некоторые значат

Comment: В вашем вопросе нажмите "Править", и в самом коде измените

Comment: Я  победила задчу. Сейчас приложу решение. Спасибо вам за наводку.

Comment: @marrowrend Добро пожаловать! Не изменяйте свой вопрос, чтобы добавить решение. Используйте "Отправить ответ", чтобы опубликовать решение. Так здесь принято, есть вопрос, есть ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например, такой вариант мне кажется более питоничным, хотя это дело вкуса:

```
print([a + b for a, b in zip(*(inp[i:] + inp[:i] for i in (-1,1)))])
```

Хотя тут сложно сказать, стал ли код более понятным или наоборот.